# Can I fetch the code for DFP ad slots for all my clients through an API?

Tags: advertising, api, google-dfp

Is there a way I can retrieve over API all the codes I get from my clients through txt files?

Now I get a bunch of files like this:

```
googletag.defineSlot('*', ][320,60],[320,100],[612,90]], 'div-gpt-ad-******')
                             .addService(googletag.pubads());
```

How can I do it over API?  Is there an example?

I need to find a way to import the ad codes because there are more than 100 DFP slots, and every-time when the client changes sizes or adds a new code I have to refresh those code snippets in my database.